# How to install the coq 8.14 (or 8.15) package with opam pin when it says it can't find it?

Tags: ocaml, coq, opam

I am on ubuntu. I'm trying to install coq 8.14. I'm sure it must exist. Why doesn't it let me install it? Commands and error msg:

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ opam switch create coq-8.14 4.07.1


<><> Installing new switch packages <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
Switch invariant: ["ocaml-base-compiler" {= "4.07.1"} | "ocaml-system" {= "4.07.1"}]



<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
∗ installed base-bigarray.base
∗ installed base-threads.base
∗ installed base-unix.base
⬇ retrieved ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1  (cached)
∗ installed ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1
∗ installed ocaml-config.1
∗ installed ocaml.4.07.1
Done.
# Run eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.14) to update the current shell environment
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.14 --set-switch)
```

err:

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ opam pin add -y coq 8.14
[ERROR] Package coq has no known version 8.14 in the repositories
```

---

Similar issue:

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ opam switch create coq-8.15 4.07.1


<><> Installing new switch packages <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
Switch invariant: ["ocaml-base-compiler" {= "4.07.1"} | "ocaml-system" {= "4.07.1"}]

<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
∗ installed base-bigarray.base
∗ installed base-threads.base
∗ installed base-unix.base
⬇ retrieved ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1  (cached)
∗ installed ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1
∗ installed ocaml-config.1
∗ installed ocaml.4.07.1
Done.
# Run eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.15) to update the current shell environment
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.15 --set-switch)
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ opam pin add -y coq 8.15
[ERROR] Package coq has no known version 8.15 in the repositories
```

cross: https://coq.discourse.group/t/how-to-install-the-coq-8-14-package-with-opam-pin-when-it-says-it-cant-find-it/1851

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version you're trying to install is 8.14.0, not 8.14. If you add the .0 it will work as you want

You can check versions [here](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/coq/coq.8.14.0/)